# gdal_viewshed's results are suffering some glitches vs visibility analysis from SAGA

Tags: gdal, saga, visibility

I'm seeing some artifacts when using [`gdal_viewshed`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_viewshed.html) vs the [`ta_lighting`](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/7.1.0/ta_lighting_6.html) tool from [SAGA-GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/). Small differences are noticeable between both visibility results.

As I wasn't sure which one was "wrong" relative to the other, I decided to trace a profile with [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/) on both visibility rasters. The observer position *and* the DEM used in both computations are exactly the same. The DEM is in a Cartesian space.

The SAGA result seems much more accurate as, in between the two grayed blocks which represent shadows in the SAGA results on the figure hereunder, gdal is telling me that this region, which should clearly be visible, is not. Both runs are what I would call "vanilla computations", i.e. no fancy options other than the mandatory ones were used.

[image: Resulting profiles on the DEM]

The highest terrain peak is at only ~580 meters from the observer on this figure. And as you don't get fooled by the vertical exaggeration in the graph, the region is relatively flat, which I guess may somehow also be an issue. I also have the feeling that gdal is doing some simplifications somewhere, because it's really much faster than SAGA's computation (less than 5 minutes vs more than an 1 hour on the same machine).

Does anybody know, by any chance, what may cause these differences? Especially what may be wrong in the GDAL based tool which I used this way:

```sh
$ gdal_viewshed -f "GTiff" -oz 5 -ox ${X} -oy ${Y} -md 10000 -vv 1 -ov -99 input_dem.tif visibility.tif
```

*(X and Y are both integer values)*

I also thought that it's because gdal is using a default coefficient to consider the effect of the curvature and refraction and not SAGA. So I ran the gdal computation again using `-cc 0` to discard this; absolutely no differences from the run without using this option. (Just in case, I also run it using `-cc 1`; this actually induces some differences, but not along the view-sight line depicted on the above graph.)

[image: GDAL default coefficient for curvature and refraction]
*Source: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_viewshed.html#cmdoption-gdal_viewshed-cc*

SAGA version is 7.1.0
GDAL version is 3.3.0dev from the Docker image [`osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-latest`](https://hub.docker.com/r/osgeo/gdal)
OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Have you read the article https://www.asprs.org/wp-content/uploads/pers/2000journal/january/2000_jan_87-90.pdf where the method that GDAL implements is defined? Perhaps if gives a hint about what might go wrong. By the article the results are not identical but the new method is much faster.

Comment: Will have a look, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It is quite possible there is a bug as well. I don't know that the gdal_viewshed code has been tested that much for 'correctness' of results.

Comment: It would be interesting to also compare the results of `r.viewshed` (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.viewshed.html) which you find in QGIS-Processing as well.